# Unity - make character jump on platform when they approach one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

Ok, I have a game where the user does not control jumping, rather they just walk the character around using a joystick. I need it to be that when they approach a platform (they walk into the area below it, or are on a platform below it, they will Mario jump onto it.

My approach would be have a box collider for the platform and one as a trigger, so when the user enters the trigger I can iTween them to a position on the platform. Is this the simplest way?

[image]

My character's rigidbody has isKinematic and Gravity checked. What is another method to make characters jump when they walk to the position of a higher platform?

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to raycast down in front of the character to detect the height difference, and if the height difference is within the correct range for the jump, make them do the jump.

But using triggers is ok, too.  Depends on the game.

Answer (score 0):

If you're platforms are always the same height (or not generated at random heights) you can use one or a series of rays.

```
public float heightOffset;
public float rayDistance;

Vector3 position = transform.position + new Vector3(0f, heighOffset, 0f);
Vector3 rotation = transform.forward;

if(Physics.Raycast(position, rotation, rayDistance))
{
    Jump();
}
```

And repeat that for every heightOffset.

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

Comment: How would you do Jump() meaning what position would you lerp to? they would always be the same height above the character but on different sides depending how the user approaches them

Comment: @UserDude You can tailor this example to your specific needs. If they are the same height you can send a raycast in each XZ direction and use the direction or the position of the collider to determine where to jump.